# Symfony and Doctrine - Multiple single table inheritance entities with an optional many to one relationship

Tags: php, entity-framework, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I'm having an issue with single table inheritance and an optional many to one mapping on a sub class.  When I try to load the parent entity through the child of a subclass the parent is loaded with no data.  I can reload the entity and get data without issue, though.  Here is a repository with an example:

https://bitbucket.org/GDIBass/relationalsingletableinheritancedoctrinebug

I've tried to recreate this in Doctrine ORM's test suite without any luck. Any ideas?

Comment: Try to use eager loading for 'fetch' option in your realtion.

http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/annotations-reference.html

Comment: @ArturYukhatov That fixed it.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try to use eager loading for 'fetch' option in your realtion.

http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/annotations-reference.html